# document must have an _id before saving mongoose error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to create a schema.

I keep getting the `document does not have an _id` error, besides the code below I did try to initialize it explicitly, but nothing works.

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     _id: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
     username: String,
     password: String
 });

var User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#_id reads:

> Mongoose assigns each of your schemas an _id field by default if one is not passed into the Schema constructor.

If you explicitly define `_id` type in the schema, it's your responsibility to set it:

```
User._id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId('000000000000000000000001');
```

Answer (score 1):

_id is the primary key for document in a mongoDB. You don't have to specify the _id in your Schema. It will be added automatically once the document is created.

Here is the sample code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var User = new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String
  },
  password: {
    type: String
  }
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('User', User);
```

Comment: Its needed to set up refs for subdocuments

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont need to define the _id. Try without and see if it works.

Also if that is not the problem try this:

```
_id: { type: Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to define _id in your schema explicity you should assign a value to "_id" for each insertation. you have two way to solve this problem : 
1. remove "_id" from your schema and mongoose generate id automatically.
2. assign a value to _id :

```
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID; // or  var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId; "but the first worked for me"
User._id = objectId('1111111111111111111');
```

Answer (score 0):

simple remove the line from your code

```
_id: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId
```